# nginx ssl_client_certificate has no effect on certificate selection on browsers when it's used with TLSv1.3

Tags: nginx, client-certificates, tls1.3, mtls

I have set up client certificate authentication on nginx using `ssl_client_certificate` and it works all fine.

[nginx documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_client_certificate) says this about `ssl_client_certificate`:

> The list of certificates will be sent to clients. If this is not
> desired, the ssl_trusted_certificate directive can be used.

My goal with this config is to make browser filter out irrelevant client certificates.

I have the following configuration (only the relevant parts) and it doesn't work. Browser brings up every client certificate in the system instead of the certificates related to CAs in `path-to-certs-pem`. I have tried Firefox, Chrome and Edge on Windows.

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_session_cache off;
ssl_verify_client optional;
ssl_client_certificate path-to-certs.pem;
ssl_verify_depth 9;
```

If I remove `TLSv1.3` it starts working, meaning browser only shows the relevant certificates. Do I maybe need to set up something extra? Or maybe there is a known nginx issue that I'm having hard time to find?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69912343/how-to-enable-certificate-authorities-extension-in-jetty-with-tls-1-3) implies that it is not inherently TLSv1.3 protocol problem at least.

Comment: We have an nginx built with wolfSSL. That seems to be the culprit since when I test this on a plain nginx, it works. I'll create an answer when I have more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a wolfSSL (v5.6.3) bug as I was testing an nginx build with wolfSSL. Rebuilding nginx with updated wolfSSL (v5.6.6) fixed the problem.

Comment: Please provide details such as the version you were previously using and the updated version.